# Error while creating PrismaClient instance in express js

Tags: javascript, express, prisma

Just started with prisma with postgress. I have a file users.js in express js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    res.send([]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now the whole app run ok but when I add this line

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

the app shows its started but cannot access `/users`, browser takes infinite loading when I go to this url.